# Survivor Space size is too small in JMap

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I have a server with 2GB as the heap size. When I gathered the JVM Memory Stats from jstat I found that minor GC is happening almost every second or every alternate second. Then I looked as jmap -heap  output, the survivor ratio is set as 8 and the eden space looks to be 682.5MB which is correct as the newRatio=2. 
As per my calculation if the survivor ratio is 8 for a 2GB heap, the S0C and S1C should be around 68MB but jmap output displays only 1.5MB.
Could somebody explain why is this happening

Here is my jmap -heap  output.

```
 Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 0
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 100
   MaxHeapSize              = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 715653120 (682.5MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 715653120 (682.5MB)
   OldSize                  = 1431830528 (1365.5MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 0 (0.0MB)

Heap Usage:
PS Young Generation
Eden Space:
   capacity = 712507392 (679.5MB)
   used     = 477707104 (455.5769958496094MB)
   free     = 234800288 (223.92300415039062MB)
   67.0459155039896% used
From Space:
   capacity = 1572864 (1.5MB)       ------ S0C
   used     = 786432 (0.75MB)
   free     = 786432 (0.75MB)
   50.0% used
To Space:
   capacity = 1572864 (1.5MB)       ------ S1C
   used     = 0 (0.0MB)
   free     = 1572864 (1.5MB)
   0.0% used
PS Old Generation
   capacity = 1431830528 (1365.5MB)
   used     = 779522880 (743.4109497070312MB)
   free     = 652307648 (622.0890502929688MB)
   54.442398367413496% used
```

Comment: *"I found that minor GC is happening almost every second or every alternate second."* that is not particularly unusual

Comment: But even minor GC is STW events, right? So will that not have any impact on JVM's performance.

Comment: What measure of performance? Latency? Throughput? Latency would suffer if you made the eden space larger to decrease the frequency of pauses. Throughput might improve a bit, but you already have a very large eden size (indicating lots of short-lived allocations), so improvements would probably be marginal.

Comment: Why `68MB`? How did you calculate that? Besides that, for some garbage collectors, adaptive sizing is enabled by default. Further, making the survivor space bigger would not change the minor gc intervalls in any way. Only the side effect of having a smaller Eden then could cause minor gc to happen *more often*.

Comment: Young generation is 682.5MB and as the survivor ratio = 8, the Eden space it 8 parts and S0 and S1 are 1 part each. So 8+1+1 = 10. So 682.5/10 = 68MB. Please correct me if this is wrong.